# category header files are not encrypted into binary

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, categories

I recently did a distribute build of my app and trying to sneak into the binary to search for any source code leaks.

I am seeing the category file which I created is not encrypted into the binary, NSDictionary+Utility.h is the file that is visible, should I do some setting so that it will move into the unix executable.

Please advice me whether a category header file will move into the unix executable file, if not I can just ignore the one which I am facing. Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. Can you post more about what tools you are using to look into the binary?

Comment: simple, change the extn of ipa to zip, extract it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

1- the header would not be part of the binary 
2 - if the category itself is not included make sure it is listed under project settings -> build phases -> compile sources
3 - if you intend this to use as a library or are trying to get your header file into the bundle you need to ensure the header is included under the library target -> build phases -> copy files and it will be included in the exports

Comment: yes i missed it, i removed the file and its gone, thanks a ton.